# Android advice on creating new Layout in Activity and dynamically changing items inside Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an `Activity` from which I get some input that I must use afterwards. I get an `Integer` number from a `NumberPicker` and an `ArrayList<String>` from a multiple choice `AlertDialog`. In that `Activity` I also have a button that starts the "game". When the button is clicked I want to open a new `Activity` so I can use the `Integer` number and the `ArrayList` but I will lose them if I go to a new `Activity`. So my guess is I should create a new `Layout` from the current `Activity` and handle the input there. I need some `TextViews` and a counter that can be dynamically changed on button click. For example the first `TextView` will be the first element of that `ArrayList`. On button clicks the counter must add 1 (counter += 1). When the counter equals the `Integer` number from the `NumberPicker` (user input) the `TextView` must change from `ArrayList(first element)` to `ArrayList(second element)`. I don't need help on the logic. This was just to clarify things. I need to know how to do that with a layout dynamically. I need some guidance how can I do that or is that the way to go (layout not `Activity`). Tutorial links/examples/advice will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the button is clicked I want to open a new Activity so I can use
>   the Integer number and the ArrayList but I will lose them if I go to a
>   new Activity.

Look into the [`putStringArrayListExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) method in the `Intent` class. This will allow you to pass your `ArrayList` to the new `Activity`:

```
List<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
int intValue = 5;

Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("int_key", intValue);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("string_key", stringArrayList);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution. I will try passing my local variables to a new Activity and tell you what happened.

Comment: How do I display/use the variables in the new Activity afterwards?
How do I display the Integer as well as the ArrayList?

Comment: You would use `getIntent().getIntExtra("int_key")` and `getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("string_key")`